# Converting MySQL 5.5 datetime binary to MySQL 5.6 (math problem)

Tags: mysql-5.5, datetime, date-math

I received a database "backup" of binary files (.frm and .ibd) that were copied from a MySQL 5.5 install.  Unfortunately, I was unable to get these files to import into a MySQL 5.5 vm that I created.  It seems that MySQL 5.6 is much happier about accepting .ibd files without a corresponding .cfg file, as it will just *assume* the layout of the binary files matches the existing schema.  Which would be fine except datetimes are stored differently between the two versions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html

I went ahead and altered a table with a datetime column in the middle of it to use datetime(6).  This will force the 8-byte datetime from the binary to fit nicely within the datetime(6) column, without overflowing into the columns to the right.

So, one problem solved: the datetime columns no longer corrupt all columns after them.  Hooray!

Next problem: now, the datetimes are incorrect.  I know this date should be within the last 10 years, but I am unsure how to correct it: `0000-00-09 04:59:58.8100193`

I assume there is a math solution for this, where I can take the data from the column and convert it in place.  Something like `execution_datetime = execution_datetime * math` and come out with the correct datetime.

Has anyone tried anything like this before?  Is there a standard code snippet for this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your assumption: "there is a math solution for this" seems wrong, based on the description of the old and new formats.

Comment: This should basically work: `day(execution_ts) * POWER(2,41) + hour(execution_ts) * POWER(2,36) + minute(execution_ts) * POWER(2,30) + second(execution_ts) * POWER(2,24) + DATE_FORMAT(execution_ts,'%f')`  ... except it doesn't :(

Comment: So, it works for *some* values.  `0000-00-09 04:59:58.8100193` becomes `20130419153249`, which means 2013-04-19 15:31:49 and is a valid datetime within a reasonable timeframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:

```
SELECT
     execution_datetime
    ,string_formatted_date
    ,STR_TO_DATE(string_formatted_date,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
FROM
    (
        SELECT
              day(execution_datetime) * POWER(2,41)
            + hour(execution_datetime) * POWER(2,36)
            + minute(execution_datetime) * POWER(2,30)
            + second(execution_datetime) * POWER(2,24)
            + (CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(execution_datetime,'%f') >= 8388608 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * POWER(2,24) /*extra second*/
            + DATE_FORMAT(execution_datetime,'%f') as string_formatted_date
        FROM execution_history
    ) a
```

It appears that there is some math error in the original import that misses a second when the 23 bit is 1.

Answer was arrived at by using the MySQL doc provided above to reverse engineer the bits and put them back in the old-style datetime format.  From there, STR_TO_DATE nicely parses the decimal representation into a datetime.  Extra second error was found through trial and error, while obsessively staring at the data and cursing.  I would not recommend this approach.